# error:unable to compile msi action install assembly

Tags: windows-installer, installaware

I have project in Visual Studio 2013.
When I build an installer with  `InstallAware X3`, it is showing me this error:

> unable to compile msi action install assembly .

Please, someone help me.

Answer (score 0):

Use this link to understand Unable to compile MSI action install assembly:-

http://www.installaware.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=6618

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Check your InstallAware installation directory and see if "depends.exe" is present there or not. If not then I am afraid your Antivirus has deleted that file and you need to either restore it from the quarantined virus chest and add it to exclusions so that it won't remove it any further, or re-install InstallAware. You will need to add full installation path to exclusions list of your antivirus. I have seen this behaviour earlier on my system and that resolved my problem.